# How I set the width of RelativeLayout to screen width?

Tags: android, width, screen, android-relativelayout, resolution

I have this `RelativeLayout` component and I want to set it to the entire screen width. How can I do that?

**atendente.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    style="@style/layoutAtendenteBalao"
    android:id="@+atendente/rltAtendenteBalao">
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="layoutAtendenteBalao">
     <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
     <item name="android:layout_height">210px</item>
     <item name="android:layout_alignParentRight">true</item>
     <item name="android:layout_alignParentBottom">true</item>
     <item name="android:layout_marginRight">176px</item>
     <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">140px</item>
     <item name="android:background">@drawable/borda_balao</item>
     <item name="android:paddingLeft">15dp</item>
     <item name="android:paddingRight">15dp</item>
     <item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
     <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
</style>
```

I have tried to put `fill_parent` to try to fill the entire width. But it does not worked. What can I do?

Comment: I can't see how the layout can fill the whole screen width when in your style, you define left and right padding and a right margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set it when you including this layout to other, like this:

```
<include android:id=”@+id/your_id”
         android:layout_width=”match_parent”
         android:layout_height=”match_parent”
         layout=”@layout/your_layout”/>
```

Comment: What is android:id and layout? Should I set this in styles.xml or atendente.xml?

Comment: If i'm right, you will use your < merge> layout as < include> in other, see the example here: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html . So, you should put @+id of this include if you need to, and layout property is name of your < merge> .xml file

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you have to add `android:layout_width` , and `android:layout_height` in your `layout node` like:

```
<RelativeLayout
    style="@style/layoutAtendenteBalao"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+atendente/rltAtendenteBalao">
```

Comment: @shkschneider I was thinking of adding this :)

Comment: He don't have to, he should do.

Answer (score 0):

use -1 and -2 for fill_parrent and wrap_content

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT

```
<style name="layoutAtendenteBalao">
     <item name="android:layout_width">-1</item>
     <item name="android:layout_height">210px</item>
     <item name="android:layout_alignParentRight">true</item>
     <item name="android:layout_alignParentBottom">true</item>
     <item name="android:layout_marginRight">176px</item>
     <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">140px</item>
     <item name="android:background">@drawable/borda_balao</item>
     <item name="android:paddingLeft">15dp</item>
     <item name="android:paddingRight">15dp</item>
     <item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
     <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
</style>
```